# Conditional writes to DynamoDB when executing an AWS glue script without Boto?

Tags: python, amazon-dynamodb, aws-glue

I've written an AWS glue job ETL script in python, and I'm looking for the proper way to perform conditional writes to the DynamoDb table I'm using as the target.

```
    # Write to DynamoDB
    glueContext.write_dynamic_frame_from_options(
        frame=SelectFromCollection_node1665510217343,
        connection_type="dynamodb",
        connection_options={
            "dynamodb.output.tableName": args["OUTPUT_TABLE_NAME"]
        }
    )
```

My script is writing to dynamo with `write_dynamic_frame_from_options`. The [aws glue connection parameter docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-programming-etl-connect.html#aws-glue-programming-etl-connect-dynamodb) make no mention of the ability to customize the write behavior in the connection options.

Is there a clean way to write conditionally without using boto?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do conditional updates with the EMR DynamoDB connector which Glue uses. It does a complete overwrite of the data. For that you would have to use Boto3 and distribute it using `forEachPartition` across the Spark executors.